# Samba, CentOS and OSX

Tags: linux, macos, centos, samba

I have a Linux server on the web with root/terminal access.

I am trying to make samba work on that machine, so I can have a drive on my MacOSX box mapped to a shared folder on the server.

I have done everything on this page:
http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sag-en-4/s1-samba-configuring.html#S3-SAMBA-GUI-USERS

created a new user, added a password to that user, etc.

I then connect to the server using the Finder. Everything goes perfect. It asks for my username/password, I type, and the folder opens on finder and show its contents.

When I drag something on the folder, finder asks me for username/password. I put the same username and password I have used to open the share and the password is not accepted.

If I am logged on the folder why is Finder asking me for a password again?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the problem. These lines were missing on the smb.conf

```
encrypt passwords = yes
smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
```